# Does anyone provide a Skype connection service?

Tags: telephony, skype

Is there a way of offering Skype access to incoming calls while keeping all telephony traffic over our chosen business telephony provision?  Is there a 3rd party who can route incoming Skype calls to our telephone system?

---

The business has had requests from contacts wanting to call us via Skype, but we want to keep all telephony via our PBX and phone lines as our geographic location limits our available internet bandwidth.  We also prevent installation of non-standard applications on desktops and do not want to add Skype to our build.

I was wondering if there were any 3rd parties that provide a connection service that would allow our contacts to call via Skype and us receive the calls via our phone system.

Answer (score 1):

Vosky has some possible options.

[Vosky](http://www.vosky.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A customer has a C3X IP PBX system with many Skype "connectors". In essence, if you call with Skype one of his accounts, one of his office VIP phones ring.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways Skype enables this:

[Skype Call forwarding](http://www.skype.com/allfeatures/callforwarding/): The client calls your Skype account with his Skype client, but the call is forwarded to your normal phone. This requires a Skype subscription on your end.

[Skype for Business](http://www.skype.com/business/solutions/medium-business/): Your PABX gets its own Skype account. Clients call this Skype account with their Skype client. You receive the call on your office phone system. There are a few variants of this solution depending on your PABX capabilities.